# using AVCaptureDevice from a secondary thread

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

My app is being tested on iphone 3g and ios 5.1 sdk and I am using `AVCaptureDevice` to open the back camera as a video input device. I am doing this from a secondary thread which I created using `detachNewThreadSelector`. I also created a preview layer. I don't see anything on the screen so I am wondering if I can create the capture session from a secondary thread. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform the work that has an effect that you want to show in your UI on a background thread.

If you do use a background thread, you have to signal to the main thread any changes and instruct it to display them. That does not seem to be a feasible way to go about this in case of video capture.

Comment: I am performing all UIKit operations on the main thread using dispatch_async.

Comment: For a video playback you would have to do this for every frame?